# How to run survival analysis on big dataset?

Tags: r, survival, large-data

I have recently been involved in a project that needs me to analyze the survival time of objects. Therefore, I plan to use the `rms` package to build a Cox model. The problem is, since the dataset I have is so big (about 450,000 instances, and each has 9 covariables), the R environment fails to handle this. Does anyone have suggestions as to how to fit these models?

Comment: maybe this question is more suitable for stackoverflow?

Comment: I am not sure this is about the limitation of R or about the time complexity of the Cox model. Therefore I put it here.

Comment: I do not have an answer for you... However, I think you should clarify whether the problem arises when your model is fitted or if it arises sooner (e.g., at the importation step)? Also, do you have any reason for not using 'coxph' from the survival package?

Comment: @ocram Thanks for your reply. I using the rms package because the validation function provided there can output the Dxy measure directly. No, the dataset can be imported smoothly, and I can even "summary(data)". So, I think it should be related to the complexity of the Cox algorithm. Is there any conclusion or report mentioned the scale ability of Cox model?  Thank you

Comment: "I think it should be related to the complexity of the Cox algorithm" ---> In order to validate this hypothesis, maybe you can try to fit your model with 'coxph' or with proc phreg (SAS) just to check whether your problem is related to 'rms'...

Comment: @ocram um... Let me check the combination of an external package for calculating the Dxy measure and the 'survival' package instead of the directly & lazy use of rms package. :-)

Comment: I don't know why R can't handle this, but I am fairly sure SAS could, if you have access to it.

Comment: Does working with all 450,000 cases really figure to give you much more useful information than analyzing a random subset of, say, 20,000?

Comment: Are you able to store the data and the error occurs when you run the survival function?  What is the error message?  Or are you not able to store a matrix that big which would be surprising...

Comment: How much RAM do you have?  Maybe using a machine with more RAM will allow you to fit the model.

Comment: Have you tried a non-Cox survival model, like a parametric model? I'm not sure if they're any easier to compute, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: I fit Cox models on data that have over 50 variables and over 2,000,000 observations on a laptop. I don't understand why this is an issue. How does the R environment "fail"? Something else is going on here.

Answer (score 2):

Using h2o is an option now: Cox PH function is available with [nightly build](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/4305/index.html) (in R only) and soon to be released with 3.20.x version. You can monitor this feature here: [PUBDEV-5019](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5019?atlOrigin=eyJpIjoiNDQ2OTA2ZjQ0YmYyNDVkZjkyMzc4N2FhOWIzYTdlNmEiLCJwIjoiaiJ9)

Obviously, with R you would need to install `h20` package by following instructions in 'INSTALL IN R' link above (copied below for clarity):

```
# The following two commands remove any previously installed H2O packages for R.
if ("package:h2o" %in% search()) { detach("package:h2o", unload=TRUE) }
if ("h2o" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) { remove.packages("h2o") }

# Next, we download packages that H2O depends on.
pkgs <- c("RCurl","jsonlite")
for (pkg in pkgs) {
  if (! (pkg %in% rownames(installed.packages()))) { install.packages(pkg) }
}

# Now we download, install and initialize the H2O package for R.
install.packages("h2o", type="source", repos="var url = location.href; var url2 = url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf("/")); document.write(url2);http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/4305/R")

# Finally, let's load H2O and start up an H2O cluster
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
```

Now, running survival model with `h2o` would be as straight forward as with `survival` package:

```
lung.hex = as.h2o(survival::lung)

covariates = c("age", "sex",  "ph.karno", "ph.ecog", "wt.loss")
lung.coxph.model = h2o.coxph(x=covariates, event_column = "status", training_frame = lung.hex,
stop_column = "time")

# print model coefficients
lung.coxph.model@model$coefficients_table
```

The code Cox PH above is equivalent to `survival` code:

```
res.cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + ph.karno + ph.ecog + wt.loss, data =  lung)
summary(res.cox)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `survival` package in R-core.

```
library(survival)
fit <- coxph(V1+V2, data=data)
```

Not sure how it compares to `rms`.

Comment: `cph` in `rms` is identical (the fitter and everything) to `coxph` unless the user specifies time-varying strata in an Anderson-Gill model. Those kinds of problems would present fairly readily as a bottleneck, I would presume.

Answer (score 1):

logistic regression might be one way to go. given the construction, you need to add time variables (most likely in spline form) into the model setup, the it can give you hazard ratio as well.

in practice, logistic regression will yield similar answer to cox model -- in many cases, even more stable.

Comment: ...unless there is censoring.